# Contao Installation Issue

Tags: php, symfony, content-management-system, contao

I am trying to install Contao on my hosting account, but I am getting an error message and am unable to solve the issue.

Live URL: https://contao.loudeffect.ml/

I read the log file but unable to figure out what is the actual issue. The version I am trying to install is: **Contao 4.4 LTS (Long-term support)**

This is the error that I see in my browser: [image: Host Error]

These are the errors from my log file:

> [2018-06-10 15:40:45] request.INFO: Matched route "contao_catch_all". {"route":"contao_catch_all","route_parameters":{"_scope":"frontend","_token_check":true,"_controller":"Contao\CoreBundle\Controller\FrontendController::indexAction","_url_fragment":"install","_route":"contao_catch_all"},"request_uri":"https://contao.loudeffect.ml/install","method":"HEAD"} []
>   [2018-06-10 15:40:45] security.INFO: Attempting SimplePreAuthentication. {"key":"frontend","authenticator":"Contao\CoreBundle\Security\ContaoAuthenticator"} []
>   [2018-06-10 15:40:45] request.INFO: Matched route "contao_catch_all". {"route":"contao_catch_all","route_parameters":{"_scope":"frontend","_token_check":true,"_controller":"Contao\CoreBundle\Controller\FrontendController::indexAction","_url_fragment":"install","_route":"contao_catch_all"},"request_uri":"https://contao.loudeffect.ml/install","method":"GET"} []
>   [2018-06-10 15:40:45] security.INFO: Attempting SimplePreAuthentication. {"key":"frontend","authenticator":"Contao\CoreBundle\Security\ContaoAuthenticator"} []
>   [2018-06-10 15:40:45] app.CRITICAL: An exception occurred. {"exception":"[object] (Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException(code: 0): An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'mlloudeffect'@'localhost' (using password: NO) at /home1/mlloudeffect/contao.loudeffect.ml/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php:103, Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException(code: 1045): SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'mlloudeffect'@'localhost' (using password: NO) at /home1/mlloudeffect/contao.loudeffect.ml/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:47, PDOException(code: 1045): SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'mlloudeffect'@'localhost' (using password: NO) at /home1/mlloudeffect/contao.loudeffect.ml/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43)"} []

I am new in this CMS please guide me so I can install Contao.

Answer (score 0):

After successful installation via ZIP archive, Contao Manager or via `composer create-project` you need to open the Contao Install Tool via the `/contao/install` route.

So in your case https://contao.loudeffect.ml/contao/install

However, something seems to be wrong with the symlinks in your case. Make sure that your hosting environment supports Contao 4 by using the most recent master version of the Contao Check: https://github.com/contao/check/zipball/master

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Now somehow I have successfully Installed contao but its showing a strange out-put like there is not style. message I am getting : "It seems that you have disabled JavaScript in your browser. The Contao back end will not work properly without JavaScript." -- But my browser JavaScript not disabled.

Comment: As I said, you should verify that your hosting environment is suitable for Contao 4 via the Contao Check.

Answer (score 0):

Contao can't connect to your database, see the last line of the error message:

[1045] Access denied for user 'mlloudeffect'@'localhost' (using password: NO) at /home1/mlloudeffect/contao.loudeffect.ml/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:47, PDOException(code: 1045): SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'mlloudeffect'@'localhost' (using password: NO) at /home1/mlloudeffect/contao.loudeffect.ml/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43)"} []

Comment: That's because the Contao Install Tool was not run yet - where you would set the database credentials. See my answer ;)